# Eclipse find source file from library

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

For debugging it is often helpful to read the library's source code. When pointing at a library function which I want to inspect and opening the context menu and click on 'Open Declaration' in my own written code I will just have a look at the corresponding header file.

How do I show the corresponding source/cpp file in Eclipse?
If I just search for the file in the source folders (using OS tools) I can't use Eclipse methods like 'Open call hierarchy', so, that won't be a satisfying solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the debugger where to find source files. In the Run or Debug Configurations dialog, there is a Source tab when you select a particular configuration. That's where you can specify so-called **Source Containers**.
For more details, see the [Eclipse CDT help page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_source.htm).

Comment: Thank you, I've found it. Shouldn't now messages like 'No source available for "cv::StereoSGBM::operator() at 0x7ffff7bb67e8"' disappear? Where can I lookup the source files? When I click on 'Open Declaration' I end up just in the header file.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not a CDT user. If you don't get any more info here I suggest trying the CDT forum at eclipse.org: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/80/